# How specifically does one incorporate known function values into InterpolatingPolynomial?

Tags: interpolation, polynomials

Say, I want to fit an $n$-degree polynomial in the variable $x$ with the command InterpolatingPolynomial, using its values at $x =1,2,...l < n+1$ , and an additional $(n+1-l)$ values at certain ("non-adjacent/remote") values of $x$. Help tells me that these values can be given as Automatic. But I don't see how specifically to do so?

Comment: My question was: Say, I want to fit a k-degree polynomial with InterpolatingPolynomial,using its values at k =1,2,...l<k+1, and an additional (k+1-l) values at certain ("non-adjacent/removed") values of k. The Help command tells me that these values can be given as Automatic. But I don't see how specifically to do so? (I don't know why the original question seemed to be truncated--so I resorted to this comment.)

Comment: Something like `InterpolatingPolynomial[Table[{k, f[k]},...], x]`?  It's not really clear to me what you want, since `k` seems to be both a fixed degree and a variable running over 1, 2,....  (I think you have a typo, perhaps?)

Comment: Oh, I guess the inequality sign (<) somehow interfered with the statement of my question. If I had put it in TeX, that certainly wouldn't have happened.

Comment: I think that the comment of MichaelE provides me with what I wanted. (But I still don't see how to use Automatic in this context.) I apologize for my original poor formulation of the question at hand.

Comment: the usage of `Automatic` is shown under Generalizations and Extensions. You can edit the question if you need to clarify things

Comment: Since determining an interpolating polynomial corresponds to solving a linear system for its coefficients, in which system each condition corresponds to a function or derivative value, I assume that `Automatic` means no value and therefore no condition is specified. For example, `{2, Automatic, 1}` specifies only $f'(2)=1$, while $f(2)$ may be anything.

Comment: Thanks george2079! I do see two specific examples of Automatic being used in Generalizations and Extensions. They appear to pertain to values of derivatives, while I wanted to specify values of the function itself. It seems to me that how the command works could be explained in a clearer fashion.

Answer (score 4):

I think the docs are a little difficult to read because they introduce the higher derivative forms after the multi variable form.  For the single variable case you can supply the function value and whatever derivatives you like at each point like this:

```
p = InterpolatingPolynomial[{
        {0, Automatic, fp0}, 
        {1, f1}, 
        {2, Automatic, Automatic, fpp2}}, x]
```

the result is quadratic since we specified three conditions:

> 1/2 (2 f1 - 2 fp0 - fpp2) + x (fp0 + (fpp2 x)/2)

`Automatic` serves as a place holder for values to be left arbitrary.

of course we get the desired result:

```
{D[p, x] /. x -> 0, p /. x -> 1, D[p, {x, 2}] /. x -> 2} // Simplify
```

> {fp0, f1, fpp2}

that said I think the actual answer you need is to simply use the second form on the docs page, specifying all the `xi` eg:

```
 InterpolatingPolynomial[{{1,f1},{2,f2},...{el,fel},{xa,fa},{xb,fb}.. },x]
```

if the first `el` x are 1,2..,el that might be done as:

```
 InterpolatingPolynomial[
   Transpose[{Range[el], {f1, f2,..,fel}}]~Join~{{xa,fa},{xb,fb},..} , x]
```